# Gradients are None for Custom Convolution Layer

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network, gradient

I have implemented the Basic MNIST model with Custom convolution layer as shown below. The problem is that the **Gradients are always 'None' for the Custom Layer** and so the learning does not happens during back propagation,  as the Grad has None values.
I have debugged the outputs of the layers during forward pass and they are OK. 
Here is the sample code, for simplicity I have passed image of 'Ones' and have just returned the matrix from the custom layer.
I have tried my best but could make it work any help is very much appreciated in advance
following code is executable and raises the

**warning**
:tensorflow:Gradients do not exist for variables ['cnn/custom_conv2d/kernel:0', 'cnn/custom_conv2d/bias:0', 'cnn/custom_conv2d_1/kernel:0', 'cnn/custom_conv2d_1/bias:0', 'cnn/custom_conv2d_2/kernel:0', 'cnn/custom_conv2d_2/bias:0'] when minimizing the loss.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from grpc.beta import interfaces
class CustomConv2D(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D):
    def __init__(self, filters,
                 kernel_size,
                 strides=(1, 1),
                 padding='valid',
                 data_format=None,
                 dilation_rate=(1, 1),
                 activation=None,
                 use_bias=True,
                 kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform',
                 bias_initializer='glorot_uniform',
                 kernel_regularizer=None,
                 bias_regularizer=None,
                 activity_regularizer=None,
                 kernel_constraint=None,
                 bias_constraint=None,
                 __name__ = 'CustomConv2D',
                 **kwargs
                 ):
        super(CustomConv2D, self).__init__(
            filters=filters,
            kernel_size=kernel_size,
            strides=strides,
            padding=padding,
            data_format=data_format,
            dilation_rate=dilation_rate,
            activation=activation,
            use_bias=use_bias,
            kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer,
            bias_initializer=bias_initializer,
            kernel_regularizer=kernel_regularizer,
            bias_regularizer=bias_regularizer,
            activity_regularizer=activity_regularizer,
            kernel_constraint=kernel_constraint,
            bias_constraint=bias_constraint,
            **kwargs )

     def call(self, input):

        (unrolled_mat, filters, shape) = self.prepare(input)
#unrolled_mat=unrolled inputs
#filters=unrolled kernels of the lAYER
#convolution through unrolling
        conv_result = tf.tensordot(unrolled_mat, filters, axes=1)
        result=tf.convert_to_tensor(tf.reshape(conv_result, shape))
        return result


    def prepare(self, matrix):
        batches,rows,cols,channels=matrix.shape
        kernel_size = self.kernel_size[0]
        unrolled_matrices=None
        # start = timer()
        for batch in range(batches):
            unrolled_maps=None
            for chanel in range(channels):
                unrolled_map = self.unroll(batch, cols, kernel_size, matrix, rows,chanel)
                if unrolled_maps is None:
                    unrolled_maps = unrolled_map
                else:
                    unrolled_maps=np.append(unrolled_maps,unrolled_map,axis=1)
            unrolled_maps = np.reshape(unrolled_maps,(-1,unrolled_maps.shape[0],unrolled_maps.shape[1]))
            if unrolled_matrices is None:
                unrolled_matrices = unrolled_maps
            else:
                unrolled_matrices = np.concatenate((unrolled_matrices, unrolled_maps))
        kernels=self.get_weights()
        kernels=np.reshape(kernels[0],(unrolled_matrices[0].shape[1],-1))
        shp=(batches,rows-(kernel_size-1),cols-(kernel_size-1),self.filters)
        matrix=unrolled_matrices
        return (matrix, kernels, shp)

    def unroll(self, batch, cols, kernel_size, matrix, rows, chanel):
        # a=np.zeros((shape))
        unrolled_feature_map = None
        for x in range(0, rows - (kernel_size - 1)):
            for y in range(0, (cols - (kernel_size - 1))):
                temp_row = None  # flattened kernal at single position
                for k in range(kernel_size):
                    for l in range(kernel_size):
                        if temp_row is None:
                            temp_row = matrix[batch, x + k, y + l, chanel]
                            # print(matrix[batch, x + k, y + l])
                        else:
                            temp_row = np.append(temp_row, matrix[batch, x + k, y + l, chanel])
                            # print(matrix[batch, x + k, y + l])
                if unrolled_feature_map is None:
                    unrolled_feature_map = np.reshape(temp_row,
                        (-1, kernel_size * kernel_size))  # first row of unrolled matrix added
                else:
                    unrolled_feature_map = np.concatenate((unrolled_feature_map, np.reshape(temp_row,
                        (-1, kernel_size * kernel_size))))  # concatinate subsequent row to un_mat
        unrolled_feature_map = np.reshape(unrolled_feature_map,( unrolled_feature_map.shape[0], unrolled_feature_map.shape[1]))
        # print(unrolled_feature_map.shape)
        matrix=unrolled_feature_map
        return matrix

class CNN(tf.keras.Model):
  def __init__(self):
    super(CNN, self).__init__()
    self.learning_rate = 0.001
    self.momentum = 0.9
    self.optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(self.learning_rate, self.momentum)
    self.conv1 = CustomConv2D(filters = 6, kernel_size= 3, activation = 'relu')  ## valid means no padding
    self.pool1 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=2) # default stride??-
    self.conv2 = CustomConv2D(filters = 16, kernel_size = 3,  activation = 'relu')
    self.pool2 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size = 2)
    self.conv3 = CustomConv2D(filters=120, kernel_size=3,  activation='relu')
    self.flatten = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()
    self.fc1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=82,kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform')
    self.fc2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=10, activation = 'softmax',kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform')
  def call(self, x):
      x = self.conv1(x)  # shap(32,26,26,6) all (6s 3s 6s 3s)
      x = self.pool1(x)  # shap(32,13,13,6) all (6s)
      x = self.conv2(x)  # shap(32,11,11,16) all(324s)
      x = self.pool2(x)  # shap(32,5,5,16)
      x = self.conv3(x)  # shap(32,3,3,120)all(46656)
      x = self.flatten(x)  # shap(32,1080)
      x = self.fc1(x)  # shap(32,82)
      x = self.fc2(x)  # shap(32,10)
      return x
  def feedForward(self, image, label):
            accuracy_object = tf.metrics.Accuracy()
            loss_object = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
            with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
                feedForwardCompuation = self(image, training=True)
                self.loss_value = loss_object(label, feedForwardCompuation)
            grads = tape.gradient(self.loss_value, self.variables)
            self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, self.variables))
            accuracy = accuracy_object(tf.argmax(feedForwardCompuation, axis=1, output_type=tf.int32), label)
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
x_train=x_train.astype('float32')
y_train = y_train.astype('float32')
image=x_train[0].reshape((1,28,28,1)) 
label=y_train[0]
cnn=CNN()
cnn.feedForward(image,label)
```

**UPDATE:** I am not using the builtin TF conv fucntion rather I am implementing my own custom convolution operation via Matrix unrolling method(unrolled map*unrolled filters). But the Tap.gradient returns "None" for the custom layers however when I use the builtin conv2d function of TF then it works fine!
I have **Added** the actual code of the operation
[Snapshot of grads while debugging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZxMh.png)

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that the `Convolution` Operation is not happening in the Class, `CustomConv2D`. Neither the `call` Method, nor the `customConv` Method is performing Convolution Operation, but it is just returning the `Input`, as it is.

1. Replacing the line, `return self.customConv(matrix)` in the `call` method of `CustomConv2D` Class with `return super(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D, self).call(matrix)` will perform the actual Convolutional Operation.
2. One more change is to invoke the `call` method of `CNN` class by including the line, `_ = cnn(X_reshaped)` before the line, `cnn.feedForward(image,label)`

By doing the above 2 changes, Gradients will be added.

Comment: I am not using the builtin TF conv fucntion rather I am implementing my own custom convolution operation via Matrix unrolling method(unrolled map*unrolled filters). But the Tap.gradient returns "None" for the custom layers however when I use the builtin conv2d function of TF then it works fine! I have Added the actual code of the operation